# Why dock points for accidental self-upvote?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, up-votes

I recently clicked on upvote on one of my questions on SO. Naturally it didn't work.Self upvoting is disabled and should be so. But I was docked 2 points for my action.

Why have this "deterrent" when "the crime" is impossible to commit?

Comment: Are you sure? Check your recent activity (the envelope), there must have been a coincidental down-vote on one of your posts.

Comment: Yes after I clicked on upvote, I was shown the error. then a down vote was shown and 2 points deducted. all this in 1 view.

Comment: That was a coincidental down-vote on the question by someone else. I've tried this on two sites and nothing untoward has happened.

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I guess someone downvoted simultaneously. resolved.

Comment: That was me. I didn't bother explaining it at the time but I downvoted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716341/show-included-files-like-dreamweaver-does-in-notepad-or-netbeans) as you acknowledge in the question that you know it is off topic but still posted it on SO anyway!

Comment: I just upvoted one of my answers and my rep was unaffected.

Comment: +1 @Martin Smith Thanks man. I deleted the question, and updated my similar question on http://superuser.com/questions/185738/dreamweaver-alternative-which-shows-included-or-linked-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You neither gain nor lose reputation for self-voting.

The votes are simply ignored.